# required field validator with javascript confirm function not validating

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I am using required field validator, which validates text box and on click of submit button i have to ask for confirm, and I use confirm() function of java script.
Issue is that when I press OK in confirmation box page post backs and required field validator  does not stops the page when I left the text box empty.
After reading posts from stackoverflow I used custom validator to stop the page, but I could not here is the code.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="one" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="one"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        OnClientClick="validate();"  ValidationGroup="one" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ValidateEmptyText="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="one" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"></asp:CustomValidator>

    <script type='text/javascript'>   
           function validate() {
            var cv = document.getElementById('MainContent_CustomValidator1');
            if (cv) {
                cv.isValid = confirm('are you sure want to update record ?');
            }
     }  </script>
```

Comment: there is no validation function for Custom validator?

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="one" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="one"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        OnClientClick="return validate();"  ValidationGroup="one" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ValidateEmptyText="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="one" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ClientValidationFunction="TextBox1Client"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

---

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>   
        function validate() {
          if(confirm('are you sure want to update record ?')){
          return true;
          }
          else
          {
          return false;
          }
       }
//you need to add a custom validot client function also  
       function TextBox1Client(sender, args) {
       //write your custom code here
        args.IsValid = false;
        //OR
        args.IsValid =true;
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: I have used your pattern and hardcoded isValid= false but it is not stopping page from post back as this function TextBox1Client(sender, args) {
   //write your custom code here
    args.IsValid = false;
   
   }

Comment: ok remove the  **OnClientClick="return validate();"** on button for a while and try. and let me know of the results

Answer (score 1):

try this code use Page_ClientValidate

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        OnClientClick="Javascript:if(Page_ClientValidate('one')){return validate();}"  ValidationGroup="one" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

correct your code like this

```
if(confirm('are you sure want to update record ?')==false){
  return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive, try this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="one" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="one"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
    OnClientClick="validate();"  ValidationGroup="one" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ValidateEmptyText="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="one" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type='text/javascript'>   
       function validate() {
        var cv = document.getElementById('MainContent_CustomValidator1');
        if (cv) {
            cv.IsValid = confirm('Are you sure want to update record?');
        }
 }  </script>
```

You didn't capitalize the i in IsValid.